# Get the minimum for each data in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min, pandas-loc

I have this data frame:

```
data = {name:  ['a', 'a','b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
    number: [32, 25, 9 , 43,8, 5, 11, 21, 0]
    }
```

and I want to get min **number** for each **name** where data in the number column for that name is not 0.
for my example, I want this result:

```
data = {'col1':  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'col2': [21, 5, 43, 8]
    }
```

I don't want the repetitive name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = df.mask(df.number.eq(0)).dropna().groupby('name', as_index = False).min()
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
  name  number
0    a    21.0
1    b     5.0
2    c    43.0
3    d     8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
out = df.loc[df.number!=0].sort_values('number').drop_duplicates('name')
Out[24]: 
  name  number
5    b       5
4    d       8
7    a      21
3    c      43
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df  = df.query('number != 0')
df.loc[df.groupby('name')['number'].idxmin().tolist()]
```

Output:

```
  name  number
7    a      21
5    b       5
3    c      43
4    d       8
```

Answer (score 2):

replace with groupby:

```
df.replace({"number":{0:np.nan}}).groupby("name",as_index=False)['number'].min()
```

---

```
  name  number
0    a    21.0
1    b     5.0
2    c    43.0
3    d     8.0
```

Cast it back to int if you want using `astype`